# C++ zbar library - unresolved external symbol

Tags: visual-studio, qr-code, zbar

I ran the following code for getting code feature for barcode using zbar library and set the properties for the project. I am getting errors such as unresolved external symbol error (LNK2019). How to resolve this error? The code for my program and the errors are attached below

```
    #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
    #include <C:/Program Files/ZBar/include/zbar.h>
    using namespace cv;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace zbar;
    typedef struct
    {
      string type;
      string data;
      vector <Point> location;
    } decodedObject;

    // Find and decode barcodes and QR codes
    void decode(Mat& im, vector<decodedObject>& decodedObjects)
    {

      // Create zbar scanner
      ImageScanner scanner;

      // Configure scanner
      scanner.set_config(ZBAR_NONE, ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE, 1);

      // Convert image to grayscale
      Mat imGray;
      cvtColor(im, imGray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

      // Wrap image data in a zbar image
     Image image(im.cols, im.rows, "Y800", (uchar*)imGray.data, im.cols * im.rows);

     // Scan the image for barcodes and QRCodes
     int n = scanner.scan(image);

     // Print results
     for (Image::SymbolIterator symbol = image.symbol_begin(); symbol != image.symbol_end(); ++symbol)
     {
        decodedObject obj;

        obj.type = symbol->get_type_name();
        obj.data = symbol->get_data();

        // Print type and data
        cout << "Type : " << obj.type << endl;`
        cout << "Data : " << obj.data << endl << endl;

        // Obtain location
        for (int i = 0; i < symbol->get_location_size(); i++)
        {
            obj.location.push_back(Point(symbol->get_location_x(i), symbol->get_location_y(i)));
        }

        decodedObjects.push_back(obj);
    }
}

// Display barcode and QR code location  
void display(Mat& im, vector<decodedObject>& decodedObjects)
{
    // Loop over all decoded objects
    for (int i = 0; i < decodedObjects.size(); i++)
    {
        vector<Point> points = decodedObjects[i].location;
        vector<Point> hull;

        // If the points do not form a quad, find convex hull
        if (points.size() > 4)
            convexHull(points, hull);
        else
            hull = points;

        // Number of points in the convex hull
        int n = hull.size();

        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            line(im, hull[j], hull[(j + 1) % n], Scalar(255, 0, 0), 3);
        }

    }

    // Display results 
    imshow("Results", im);
    waitKey(0);

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    // Read image
    Mat im = imread("zbar-test.jpg");

    // Variable for decoded objects 
    vector<decodedObject> decodedObjects;

    // Find and decode barcodes and QR codes
    decode(im, decodedObjects);

    // Display location 
    display(im, decodedObjects);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The errors are as follows,

[image: errors]

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Instead, paste the text in a code block.

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs OK! You just need to refer the `Zbar library` on:

`Project Properties -> Linker -> Input -> C:\opencv\Zbar\lib\libzbar64-0.lib`    (for example)

With kind regards,

`PFG`